# Copy resources from c# pjct to a windows directory

Tags: c#, resources, directory, temp

how can i copy a file in my project resources to a temp directory using C#

i have install.bat file in my project resources  folder i want to copy this into c:\ directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
File.Copy(@"Resources\install.bat", @"C:\directory\install.bat");
```

**note**: you should have Resources folder in Debug\bin. (if there isn't one, click on property of install.bat file in Visual Studio solution exprorer and set 'Copy to Output Directory' to 'Copy always'

Comment: but when it execute it say the file is already there but i remove all files in destination folder but that error comes again

Answer (score 10):

My project can copy a dll as resource in a directory, maybe this wil work for you:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\filename.extension", Properties.Resources.install);
```